# CiviCRM & Quickbooks - What's the best way to achieve membership type accounting coding?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, accounting, quickbooks

Been looking at Justin @ Agilewares fantastic QuickBooks extension and I had a question around our specific scenario and I'm not entirely sure if (or how) it can achieve what we need. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

We have 5 different paid membership tiers that each has its own individual code in Quickbooks (Bronze to Diamond). Does the extension have the granular functionality to people able to code membership levels, vs just 'member dues'.

Same with donations, we have different donations types with different codes. Can these be aligned in CiviCRM -> Quickbooks?

Sorry if basic questions, new to the accounting side of things.

Thanks!